# Undefined index when calling htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: test
```

With reference to this line:

```
$token = htmlspecialchars($_GET["test"]);
```

Do I need to define `test` somewhere even though I'm trying to read it from a URL?

-

-EDIT-

I had actually looked at the answer linked as a duplicate before posting this but couldn't see anything in it relating to using `htmlspecialchars` which I thought was causing the problem.

Comment: Try outputting `var_dump($_GET)` and see if "test" key exists. It'd be good if you do an `isset` check before you use it directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable doesn't exists. Use isset to check this

```
if(isset($_GET["test"]))
    $token = htmlspecialchars($_GET["test"]); 
else
    echo "variable test doesn't exist";
```

Comment: All informative answers here but I used this one and it worked so will accept this as answer as soon as SO allows. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable the error reporting on by using the below line before the script runs

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then check the variable exists before you use by using the isset() function in php

```
isset($_GET["test"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that `$_GET["test"]` exists before you apply `htmlspecialchars` to it. This sets the token value to `null` if `$_GET["test"]` is not set.

```
$token = isset($_GET["test"]) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["test"]) : null;
```

Comment: It checks to see if `$_GET["test"]` is set before trying to perform an operation on something which doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supplying the test variable in the GET request therefore it displays this error.
Try using the code suggested by Gravy. Though this will make the token null if test is not received in URL.
IF token is a mandatory requirement to be received them you can do something like

```
if(isset($_GET['test'])) {
    $token = htmlspecialchars($_GET["test"]);
}else{
    // do stuff when you dont get test. Return or output error etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned , to read from url .. It doesn't guaranteed that you page is requested through get ,, it may be post .. To work on both use

```
$token = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["test"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

$token = htmlspecialchars(@$_GET["test"]);

Use @ to ignore notice error

Comment: You should rarely (if ever) ignore a error / notice, instead you should handle it.